# Replacing Ecwid checkout button

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to interrupt the Ecwid checkout process, collect some extra information, and then go to their checkout and stuff that extra information into the Notes field, and then proceed with normal checkout.

So to attempt the first part, I was trying to use the Javascript API to replace the checkout button. I added this code:

```
Ecwid.OnPageLoaded.add(function(page) {
    console.log(page.type);
    if (page.type == 'CART') {
        $button = $('div.ecwid-productBrowser-cart-checkoutButton');
        $parent = $button.parent();
        $button.hide();
        $('<button>Delivery Options</button>').appendTo($parent);
    }
});
```

(Yeah, I'm going to change the button to a link later). The code does what you expect, it finds the "Checkout" button, and adds my button. However, less than a second later, something changes it back. I can't follow their code logic because they've obfuscated it so well, so I'm not sure exactly what they're doing, but it seems to involve some jsonp stuff to inject little scripts into the DOM.

I can set up a timer and put it back after they changed it back, but I'm looking for something cleaner. Is there an event I can use?

Comment: @rene I did flag it as spam. I just wanted to make sure the spammers phone number didn't get into Google. SO is so good at getting into Google rankings really fast.